# Difference between two adjacent numbers in array

Tags: javascript

I start my adventure with AngularJS and I have a question, is it possible to calculate the difference between two numbers?

After extracting data from SQL - I get a table like this, I would like to receive a difference between visits on days 1 <- 2, 2 <-3, etc.

[image]

Comment: Use subtraction...

Answer (score 1):

I think its in the scope of simple javascript.

If you have your data in an array just use a simple iteration on it and compare the visit of current day to the visits from previous day.

A very simple solution might be:

```js
var visitsArr = [38,29,18,29,28,18,24];

checkVisitsDiff(visitsArr);


function checkVisitsDiff(arr){
  //Input validation check 
  if(!arr || arr.length <2){
     throw "Bad input!";
  }

  //If input is ok - Start from second element
  for(var i=1; i<arr.length; i++){
      var currentElement  = arr[i];
      var previousElement = arr[i-1];
      console.log("The difference from visit " + i + " to visit " +(i-1) + " is: " +(currentElement-previousElement));
  }
}
```

I hope this what you asked.

Comment: Your code will show NaN if arr is empty, probably should add a check for that.

Answer (score 0):

Use Array methods:

```js
var visitsArr = [38,29,18,29,28,18,24];

var diffs = visitsArr.slice(1).map((x,i)=> x-visitsArr[i]);

diffs.forEach((x,i) => console.log(
   `Visits from day ${i+1} to day ${i+2} increased by ${x}`
));
```

For more information, see

- [MDN JavaScript Reference - Array.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)
- [MDN JavaScript Reference - Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [MDN JavaScript Reference - Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I understand that in AngularJS I can upload to app.filter app? e.g. using ng-option? He combines and unfortunately does not go

Comment: If you are having problem with the [ng-options directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions), then please [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Be sure to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That code should be… **Complete** – Provide all parts needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: And is it possible to subtract: 7 -> 6 day, 6 -> 5 day, 5->4... - that is from the end?

Comment: Yes, it is trivial and obvious how to modify the code to do that.